# pandas df.ix[number, column] accesses different scalar type than df[column].ix[number]

Tags: python, pandas

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'frames':np.arange(3), 'r':np.repeat(3, 3), \
'x':np.random.rand(3), 'y':list('041')}, index=list('abc'))

  frames  r       x   y
a      0  3  0.1241  '0'
b      1  3  0.4109  '4'
c      2  3  0.8714  '1'
```

Then `type(df1.ix[0, 'y']), type(df1['y'].ix[0])` returns `(str, str)` as expected.

However, after changing the 'y' column dtype to integer with `df1['y'] = df1['y'].astype(int)`:

Now, `type(df1.ix[0, 'y']), type(df1['y'].ix[0])` returns `(numpy.float64, numpy.int64)`.

This seems like very inconsistent behavior to me. Shouldn't both methods return the same scalar type? I realize I am ignorant to the inner workings of `ix`. Does anyone know why or how this happens?

And more importantly, what is the most robust way to access scalars, such that they preserve their type?

Comment: Fixed the typo, thanks! Yeah, I am quite puzzled by that. And after checking the `df1.dtypes` before and after the column assignment it shows that at the 'DataFrame' level the dtype successfully changes to int.  But the scalar access changing the dtype is still a mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happens because pandas `Series` could be only with one type, when you are doing `df1.ix[0,'y']` you accessing to the first row to the column `y`. Row contains `float` variable, so everything is converted to `np.float64`. When you're calling `df1['y'].ix[0]` you accessing to the column `y` which has `dtype` `np.int32` to the first element. Everything works as expected. So for your question about most robust way I think second method is preferable because you always know your `dtype` of the column or you could easily check it while for `row` it could be converted automatically.

Btw if you are accessing to the element by position (when you are using column) it's preferrable to use [`iloc`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjp5uaPnabKAhVHz3IKHSwYCMAQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fversion%2F0.17.1%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.iloc.html&usg=AFQjCNGRd6Fb6DHL3kZ54D-eG8oZRBnvMg&cad=rja). From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ix.html) for `ix`:

> `.ix` supports mixed integer and label based access. It is primarily
>   label based, but will fall back to integer positional access unless
>   the corresponding axis is of integer type. `.ix` is the most general and
>   will support any of the inputs in `.loc` and `.iloc`. `.ix` also supports
>   floating point label schemes. `.ix` is exceptionally useful when dealing
>   with mixed positional and label based hierarchical indexes.
>
> However, when an axis is integer based, ONLY label based access and
>   not positional access is supported. Thus, in such cases, it’s usually
>   better to be explicit and use `.iloc` or `.loc`

If you need to access to only scalar you should also consider [`iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html) method. From [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fast-scalar-value-getting-and-setting):

> Since indexing with `[]` must handle a lot of cases (single-label
>   access, slicing, boolean indexing, etc.), it has a bit of overhead in
>   order to figure out what you’re asking for. If you only want to access
>   a scalar value, the fastest way is to use the `at` and `iat` methods,
>   which are implemented on all of the data structures.

**Benchmarking:**

```
In [129]: %timeit df1.y.ix[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.2 us per loop

In [130]: %timeit df1.y.iloc[0]
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.6 us per loop

In [131]: %timeit df1.y.iat[0]
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.8 us per loop
```

Comment: Neat answer.  It's interesting that when accessing a row, types are coerced to the least general type for the entire row, but it makes sense now.

Comment: For me, I needed to use a mixture of integer and label indexing, which  is why I used `.ix` , but in light of the information you gave I might try an all integer indexing setup. Thanks!